# When display:none is set for div , animate botton divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have html as

```
<div id ="div-1>
  //some content
</div>
<div id ="div-2>
  //some content
</div>
```

when i set display:none for div-1 is hides immediately , and div-2 comes on top abrubtly.

Is there any way that div-2 slides out to top, instead of coming directly.

**PS**

I have tried transition with max-height set to zero for div 1 but , it's not working.

**EDIT**

Hi, i am working on  a js lib to swipe out html elements.

I just want a animated scroll for bottom elements , when div on top is set to display:none.

I only have reference for first div.

Comment: How are you setting the display to none? Be specific - include your code.

Comment: @cale_b There isn't any question of how they are applying the CSS

Comment: the only to do it without it shifting is to have one positioned absolutely

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question, NOT just a link to a github repo.  When your repo changes or goes away, this question has zero value for future visitors.

Comment: @cale_b As i said, i only have reference of first div, and just needs to animate when first div is hidden. So there is no need for code. It is pretty basic question.

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting display:none, you could set opacity:0 on div-1 and position div-2 on top of div-1 by using z-index and either css transitions to change the position, or use jquery animate.

Comment: Hi, i am developing a js lib to swipe out html elements.
I don't have reference of bottom div. only of first div.
see -> https://github.com/harrysaini/swipe-fade-out
and want a animated scroll for bottom elements , when div on top is set to display:none.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the slideUp jQuery method to easily achieve this.
[jQuery slideUp() doc](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

#### Working example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideUp demo</title>
  <style>
    div {
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <button>Hide One</button>
    <input type="text" value="One">
  </div>

  <div>
    <button>Hide Two</button>
    <input type="text" value="Two">
  </div>

  <div>
    <button>Hide Three</button>
    <input type="text" value="Three">
  </div>

  <div id="msg"></div>

  <script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function() {
        $("#msg").text($("button", this).text() + " has completed.");
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to do it using only css and javascript, without jquery.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried with max-height property.But it just mixes the inner content of div. Inner content is not hidden with parent, and overlaps with other html.